# jboss 6.x: sending e-Mails if any type of Exception is thrown

Tags: java, email, jboss, jboss6.x

I am using JBoss for my application and I want to setup automatic email sending feature in JBoss. Please find below code of my JBossp-logging.xml file:

```
<log4j-appender name="SMTP" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
<error-manager>
        <only-once/>
    </error-manager>

    <level name="ERROR"/>

    <properties>
        <param name="SMTPHost" value="smtp.test.com" />
        <param name="From" value="test1@gmail.com" />
        <param name="To" value="test2@gmail.com" />
        <param name="Subject" value="Testing Log4j mail notification" />
        <property name="bufferSize">50</property>
    </properties>

    <formatter>
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%d %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n"/>
    </formatter>
</log4j-appender>
```

After adding this when I start JBoss server, I am getting following error:

```
15:19:15,149 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Parse: name=vfs:///D:/2.0.10branch/platformV2/jboss-2.0.10/server/default/deploy/jboss-logging.xml state=PreParse mode=Manual requiredState=Parse: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error creating managed object for vfs:///D:/2.0.10branch/platformV2/jboss-2.0.10/server/default/deploy/jboss-logging.xml
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:383) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:343) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:315) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.deploy(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:255) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_30]

Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source: vfs:///D:/2.0.10branch/platformV2/jboss-2.0.10/server/default/deploy/jboss-logging.xml@103,52
at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:224) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
at org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:178) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
at org.jboss.xb.util.JBossXBHelper.parse(JBossXBHelper.java:257) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
at org.jboss.xb.util.JBossXBHelper.parse(JBossXBHelper.java:231) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(SchemaResolverDeployer.java:137) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(SchemaResolverDeployer.java:121) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parseAndInit(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:352) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parseAndInit(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:334) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parse(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:251) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:369) [:2.2.2.GA]

Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBRuntimeException: {urn:jboss:logging:6.0}param not found as a child of {urn:jboss:logging:6.0}properties in sequence: {urn:jboss:logging:6.0}property*
at org.jboss.xb.binding.sunday.unmarshalling.ElementPosition.nextPosition(ElementPosition.java:199) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
at org.jboss.xb.binding.sunday.unmarshalling.ElementPosition.startParticle(ElementPosition.java:475) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
at org.jboss.xb.binding.sunday.unmarshalling.SundayContentHandler.startElement(SundayContentHandler.java:202) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.startElement(SaxJBossXBParser.java:401) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.xinclude.XIncludeHandler.emptyElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:209) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
```

Please help to enable Sending email alerts enable when exception throws.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive a stacktrace like this, you need to look at what it says, and if there are one or more "caused by" exceptions, what they are. That is normally where the problem is.

In your case, the exception is:

```
15:19:15,149 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Parse: 
name=vfs:///D:/2.0.10branch/platform
...
Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source: 
vfs:///D:/2.0.10branch/platformV2/jboss-2.0.10/server/default/deploy/
jboss-logging.xml@103,52
...
Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBRuntimeException: {urn:jboss:logging:6.0}param 
not found as a child of {urn:jboss:logging:6.0}properties in sequence:
{urn:jboss:logging:6.0}property*
```

So you can see that JBoss is unable to parse the file jboss-logging.xml at line 103, character 52. And you can see that it is complaining that `param` not found as a child of {urn:jboss:logging:6.0}`properties` in sequence: {urn:jboss:logging:6.0}`property*`

So the jboss-logging.xml is incorrect; specifically you cannot have a param element as a child of the properties element.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I understand that but want to know about that how can I correct XML file means can you please let me know which DTD/XSD file need to update for this?

And another thing everywhere on internet this type of structure I am getting. can you please help me to come out of this issue?